# How to pipe what is written to Stream 1 into Stream 2?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

This is my scenario:

```
producer.WriteStream(stream);
consumer.ReadStream(stream);
```

I want something that allows the bytes generated by the `producer` to be progressively transfered to the `consumer`.

I could write everything to a `MemoryStream`, then rewind it and read it on the `consumer`, but that is causing huge memory consumption.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use 2 instances of [PipeStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.pipestream(v=vs.110).aspx), 1 to read (client) and 1 to write (server).

Comment: Thanks @Amit, can you elaborate on how to "bind" these streams together.. it's not clear to me.

Comment: If you need to transfer data from one stream to another, you normally do this by reading chunks (e.g. 1K or 4K) from the source and put them into the destination until the source stream is empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using pipes as the underlying transport for your data, you can have a "write stream" (server) and a "read stream" (client) that allow for such communication mechanism.

It quite simple to do, either with anonymous pipes or named pipes (if you need inter-proc communication). To create your the pipe streams:

```
AnonymousPipeServerStream pipeServer = new AnonymousPipeServerStream();
AnonymousPipeClientStream pipeClient =
  new AnonymousPipeClientStream(pipeServer.GetClientHandleAsString());
```

Now you can use these as to write & read:

```
producer.WriteStream(pipeServer);
// somewhere else...
consumer.ReadStream(pipeClient);
```

Comment: That is much easier than my solution.

Answer (score 3):

I just threw this together for fun, it is untested and may have a few bugs. You just pass `ReaderStream` to the reader and `WriterStream` to the writer.

```
public class LoopbackStream
{
    public Stream ReaderStream { get; }
    public Stream WriterStream { get; }

    private readonly BlockingCollection<byte[]> _buffer;

    public LoopbackStream()
    {
        _buffer = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();
        ReaderStream = new ReaderStreamInternal(_buffer);
        WriterStream = new WriterStreamInternal(_buffer);
    }

    private class WriterStreamInternal : Stream
    {
        private readonly BlockingCollection<byte[]> _buffer;

        public WriterStreamInternal(BlockingCollection<byte[]> buffer)
        {
            _buffer = buffer;
            CanRead = false;
            CanWrite = true;
            CanSeek = false;
        }

        public override void Close()
        {
            _buffer.CompleteAdding();
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            var newData = new byte[count];
            Array.Copy(buffer, offset, newData, 0, count);
            _buffer.Add(newData);
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override bool CanRead { get; }
        public override bool CanSeek { get; }
        public override bool CanWrite { get; }

        public override long Length
        {
            get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        }

        public override long Position
        {
            get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
            set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        }
    }
    private class ReaderStreamInternal : Stream
    {
        private readonly BlockingCollection<byte[]> _buffer;
        private readonly IEnumerator<byte[]> _readerEnumerator;
        private byte[] _currentBuffer;
        private int _currentBufferIndex = 0;

        public ReaderStreamInternal(BlockingCollection<byte[]> buffer)
        {
            _buffer = buffer;
            CanRead = true;
            CanWrite = false;
            CanSeek = false;
            _readerEnumerator = _buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _readerEnumerator.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            if (_currentBuffer == null)
            {
                bool read = _readerEnumerator.MoveNext();
                if (!read)
                    return 0;
                _currentBuffer = _readerEnumerator.Current;
            }

            var remainingBytes = _currentBuffer.Length - _currentBufferIndex;
            var readBytes = Math.Min(remainingBytes, count);
            Array.Copy(_currentBuffer, _currentBufferIndex, buffer, offset, readBytes);
            _currentBufferIndex += readBytes;

            if (_currentBufferIndex == _currentBuffer.Length)
            {
                _currentBuffer = null;
                _currentBufferIndex = 0;
            }

            return readBytes;
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override bool CanRead { get; }
        public override bool CanSeek { get; }
        public override bool CanWrite { get; }

        public override long Length
        {
            get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        }

        public override long Position
        {
            get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
            set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very elegant solution @Scott, and nice use of framework classes. Just a couple of small bugs (fixed in my edit) - it works very well now.
Nicely done, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [Pipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipelines.pipe?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) in [System.IO.Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines) namespace was designed for.

```cs
var pipe = new Pipe();
PipeReader reader = pipe.Reader;
PipeWriter writer = pipe.Writer;
```

Now pass the two instances to your consumer and producer logic, respectively.